# Convex Hull of a balanced set is balanced

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

A set $A$ is balanced if and only if $\alpha A \subseteq A$ for any scalar $\alpha \in [-1,1].$

conv$A = \{ \lambda a + (1-\lambda)b: a,b\in A, \lambda \in [0,1] \}.$

Show that if $A$ is a balanced subset of a vector space $V,$ then $\text{conv}(A)$ is balanced.

My attempt: Let $x \in \text{conv}(A)$ and $\lambda \in [-1,1].$
        By the definition of $\text{conv}(A),$ there exists $\mu \in [0,1],$ $a,b\in A$ such that $x = \mu a + (1-\mu)b.$
        It follows that $\lambda x = \lambda \mu a + \lambda (1-\mu) b.$
        Since $\lambda \mu, \lambda (1-\mu) \in [-1,1],$ we have $\lambda x \in \text{conv}(A).$

Question: Where did I use the condition that $A$ is balanced?

Comment: What is the definition of convA?

Comment: Added the definition for conv$(A)$

Comment: I don't really follow the last line. I think the argument should continue by noting that $\lambda a$ and $\lambda b$ are in $A$ since $A$ is balanced. Applying the definition of $\mbox{conv}(A)$ will give you $\lambda x \in \mbox{conv}(A)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in $Conv$A.$ Then there are $a,b\in A$ such that $x=ta+(1-t)b$ for $0\le t\le 1.$

If $-1\le \lambda\le 1$ we have then $\lambda x=t\lambda a+(1-t)\lambda b.$

But $A$ is balanced so $\lambda a,\lambda b\in A,\ $ which implies that $\lambda x\in $Conv$A$ and so Conv$A$ is balanced.

Comment: Why can't I say that since $-1 \leq t\lambda \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq \lambda(1-t) \leq 1$, $\lambda x \in$ con$(A)$ instead of applying $A$ being balanced?

Comment: the fact that $\lambda x = \lambda \mu a + \lambda (1-\mu) b.$ doesn't prove that $\lambda x\in $Conv$A$.

Comment: I understand now. Note that $\lambda \mu + \lambda(1-\mu) \neq 1,$ therefore we cannot conclude that $\lambda x \in $ conv$(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda(-a)+(1-\lambda)(-b)$ is in conv$A$ .

Comment: This should really have proper formatting.